# a special case about subnet mask calculation

Tags: ip, subnet, ip-address

I have an IP addresses **192.168.2.0** and a subnet **192.168.1.0/10**

And I have two questions. (1) Is **192.168.1.0/10** legal? As the 9th least significant bit is not 0.

And if (1) is true, does **192.168.2.0** belongs to this subnet? According to the definition, I first calculate **192.168.2.0 & 255.255.252.0**. The result is **192.168.0.0**, which is not equal to 192.168.1.0. However, the first 22 bits of the two addresses are the same. It is confusing...

Comment: No. That did not mention my case. @MadHatter

Comment: Is this a real problem that you're facing or a theoretical problem?

Comment: @bobzc: This question explains *everything* you need to know about subnetting and if you read and understand it, you can answer your own question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subnet mask - /10 says how many bits designate NETWORK part of the address (so illegal/legal not exactly applicable here),and in turn how many bits AFTER designate HOST bits. 
So :
1) 192.168.1.0/10  - legal 
2) 192.168.2.0 - yes , it is included . The whole range here is:
From Network address: #ipcalc -n 192.168.1.0/10
NETWORK=192.128.0.0
To Broadcast address:
ipcalc -b 192.168.1.0/10
BROADCAST=192.191.255.255

so it is 192.128.0.0 - 192.191.255.255